# Using python loops in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, loops, selenium-webdriver

I wrote a script to pull elements from a search page. Pulling the title, price, and link from the search results.I need to capture these elements for all 25 results on the page.

I am using Xpath, and each result has an incremental div number.  So I wanted to use a loop so that it can add the incremental div number to each of my 3 extractions.

I am new to loops and not sure how I can insert an incremental number in the Xpath using loops.
For the title of the search result I am using the following code:

```
title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search']/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/h2/a/span").text
```

This prints the headline for the first search result.

For the next result the Div below increases by 1. Example:

**First result:**

```
//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[1]/div[1]
```

**Second result is:**

```
//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[1]/div[2]
```

**Third result is:**

```
//*[@id="search"]/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[1]/div[3]
```

and so on for 25 results total.

How can I use loops in python to increase that particular div by one until 25 is reached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it,

```
ResultsCount = 25

for i in range(ResultsCount):
    title = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search']/div[1]/div[2]/div/span[3]/div[1]/div["+str(i+1)+"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/h2/a/span").text
    print(title)
```

Comment: Thanks Sureshmani, that works for the first extraction, the title.  If i want to do the same for the price and link, do i need to use another loop for each, or do i need to reset the first loop?